# magento custom admin url redirects to homepage

Tags: redirect, nginx, magento-1.9

We just moved to another server, we are using Nginx as webservice
and we are using custom admin url for magento 1.9 like **admin.domain.com**
I can access magento admin through this url: https://admin.domain.com/index.php/admin

so is there anyway I can access it using this url only **admin.domain.com**

**here it's my nginx config**

```
server {
listen      888.888.888.888:80;
server_name domain.com *.domain.com www.domain.com;
root        /home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html;
index       index.php index.html index.htm;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/domain.com.log combined;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/domain.com.bytes bytes;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/domains/domain.com.error.log error;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    expires 30d;
}
location /app/                       { deny all; }
location /includes/                  { deny all; }
location /lib/                       { deny all; }
location /media/downloadable/        { deny all; }
location /pkginfo/                   { deny all; }
location /report/config.xml          { deny all; }
location /var/                       { deny all; }

location /var/export/ {
    auth_basic              "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file    htpasswd;
    autoindex               on;
}
location  /. {
    return 404;
}

location @handler {
    rewrite / /index.php;
}

location ~ .php/ {
    rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    expires off;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 900s;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9002;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
rewrite ^/minify/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;
rewrite ^/skin/m/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;

location /lib/minify/ {
    allow all;
}
gzip on;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length  256;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon;

error_page  403 /error/404.html;
error_page  404 /error/404.html;
error_page  500 502 503 504 /error/50x.html;

location /error/ {
    alias   /home/admin/web/domain.com/document_errors/;
}

location ~* "/\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$" {
    deny    all;
    return  404;
}

location /vstats/ {
    alias   /home/admin/web/domain.com/stats/;
    include /home/admin/web/domain.com/stats/auth.conf*;
}

include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.inc*;
include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phppgadmin.inc*;
include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/webmail.inc*;

include     /home/admin/conf/web/nginx.domain.com.conf*;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

> 1. Create two exact servers
>
>    1. Make sure that your files are sync'd (root
>         /var/www/vhosts/example.com;)
>    2. Your admin server will become your master and you can use Lsync to
>         make sure they are always sync'd
>    3. Domain admin.example.com will have one IP and your production server
>         will have another Ip address
>    4. You nginx config files can be identical.
>    5. In Magento you will choose custom url for admin and point that URL
>         To your new admin server
>    6. Any files changes and uploads will go to Admin and will get sync'd
>         to your slave server via the Lsync process.
>    7. You can run Redis through ElastiCache or simply run it on the admin
>         server
>    8. You should use RDS for your database server
>         Store sessions and cache in REDIS
>    9. DO NOT SYNC YOUR VAR FOLDER

Comment: my frontend and backend on the same server, I think nginx configuration need to be fixed with subdomain